# invalid operation exception when the column is a check box and use a converter

Tags: c#, mvvm, datagrid, converters

I have a datagrid and one of the columns are ths:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="MyColumn" Binding="{Binding ConverterParameter=this, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=myCOnverterValueConverter}}" />
```

If I use a text column I don't have any problem, but if I change it to check box column I get the exception invalid operation exception, and the code does not get the converter code.

If I use a check box column and I don't use any converter I don't have any problem.

How can I use a converter with check box columns in a dataGrid?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt the problem associated is `Mode` property of the `Binding` which is `TwoWay` by default and since you are binding it to `ConverterParameter` you should set the this to `OneWay`.
If you need how you can implement `TwoWay` binding read the [Editing data section](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20719.wpf-displaying-and-editing-many-to-many-relational-data-in-a-datagrid.aspx?Sort=MostUseful&PageIndex=1) which provide a nice explanation about it.
The above article also explains how we can use `ConverterParameter` correctly with `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` in the *Displaying data section*.

Just try this hope it works,

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="MyColumn" Binding="{Binding ConverterParameter=this, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=myCOnverterValueConverter}}" />
```

Comment: It workd fine. Thanks so much, and to explain the reason of the problem.